# Concatenate the output of multiprocessing function using python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have dataset with 64 column, what i want is to find 30 feature for each column. I have 12 processor system and I want is to split the column across these processor.
For example processor 1 find features of 1-8 column, processor 2 find features of 8-16 columns and so on. At the end what i want is to concatenate the output of each subprocess.

```
def process(i,subject):
    X=fe.fit_transform(subject[:,i:i+8])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    subject=np.load('data.npy')
    process_list=[]
    for i,j in enumerate(range(0,56,8)):   
        process_list.append(Process(target = process,args = (i,subject)))
        process_list[i].start()
        process_list[i].join()
```

what is want is to concatenate the output X from function process. In simple way we can append the X in a list and then concatenate it. But i am confused how to do it. Do it need to append inside function or below `if __name__ == '__main__':`

**Other Way**

The other way i am trying is using pool. Here is the approach

```
def cal_feature(subject):
    return fe.fit_transform(subject)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   subject=np.load('data.npy')

    p=Pool()
    result=p.map(cal_feature,subject)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

In this appraoch i am unable to understand. what things are bing shared across process. Do feature split for processor, or column split for processors. By feature split, i mean processor-1 take 5 out of 30 feature for all 64 column, processor-2 take next 5 feature for 64 columns.
Or processor-1 take 1-8 columns for all features and processor-2 next 8 columns.
Second approach is giving me this error
IndexError: too many indices for array.

**EDIT**

```
import numpy as np
data= np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(30, 10, 20))
def cal_feature(subject):
    return np.mean((subject),-1)    
result=cal_feature(data)    
print(result)
```

This is simplified version of my work. Instead of just mean feature, there are other features also, which are calculate by an other function.
Talking about above simplified example, axis 0 shows trials, axis 1 show columns, axis 2 show data points. `cal_feature` calculate mean of each trial. This way we get a result having shape of `(30,10)`.
Suppose i have 2 processors and what i want is to calculate mean of first 5 columns and all 30 trials by one processor, resulting a shape of `30,5`. and processor 2 calcualte mean of next 5 column, resulting in shape of `30,5`. Concate them and get a final result of `30,10` shape

Comment: what is the shape of your `subject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
p = Pool(20) # your max workers = 2 * num cpu cores 
result = p.map(cal_feature, np.split(subject,20))
```

Comment: subject i am passing is a 3d array. and i am getting this error
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' after changing numpy array to list

Comment: @TalhaAnwar try now

Comment: please show an  example of how it works with one column or without multiprocessing

Comment: yes, the sample random number example work, without pool multiprocessing. `fe` is a package just like numpy which calculate some feature including mean, standard deviation, variance and many more complex one. If the multiprocessing work with `np.mean` it would work with `fe` also

Comment: what is the shape of your subject

Comment: it is in same order as in random sample. Like trials,columns,points. as in above sample case it is `(30,10,20)`, but for real data its `(100,64,3072)`

Comment: @TalhaAnwar try now,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198385/discussion-between-talha-anwar-and-rusu-ro1).

Comment: It actually split the trials. not the columns. But i think it is even not bad. But if there is way to split columns , let me know. Btw thanks for such a great help

Comment: what are the columns in 3d matrix?

Comment: @TalhaAnwar check now